# Why does Interop opens a document by path, which does not exist in the directory?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, openxml

I just made a document, opened it with Interop in Visual Studio with C#, converted it to XPS and displayed it in a DocumentView.
The document has form fields with a default text. As I opened the document in the DocumentView everything worked fine.

Next I added some form fields with a text and a default text, but in the DocumentView nothing happened after I relaod the document to it. Neither the input text nor the default text from the new form fields showed up.
So I watched the xml of the .docm file and I saw the correct values.

Then I deleted the .docm and accidently I started the program.
The DocumentView with the same document showed up, how is that possible.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Temp files.....